# Complex extensions with multiple type constraints

Tags: generics, type-conversion, protocols, swift5, decoding

I'm trying to extend a type with nested constraints, I'm a bit lost so as to how achieve something like the following:

```swift
extension KeyedDecodingContainer where K : CodingKey,
                                       K : RawRepresentable,
                                       RawValue : AnyHashable {

  /// A helper method 
  func decode<T>(into object: inout [K.RawValue : Any], _ type: T.Type, 
                 forKey: key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws where T : Decodable { 
    object[key.rawValue] = try self.decode(type, forKey: key) as Any
  }
}
```

Example usage would be:

```swift
struct Value: Decodable {
   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case id
   }

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let c = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      
      var object = [String : Any]()
      try c.decode(into: &object, Int.self, forKey: .id)
   }
}
```

Is it even possible at all? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are nearly there!

- `KeyedDecodingContainer` doesn't have a `RawValue` type, it's `K` that does, as `K` conforms to `RawRepresentable`
- `AnyHashable` is a concrete implementation of `Hashable`. Use `Hashable` when you want to constrain generic parameters.
- `KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key` can be simplified to just `Key`, since you are in the scope of `KeyedDecodingContainer<K>`.
- You don't need `as Any`. Everything can be implicitly converted to `Any`.

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer where K : CodingKey,
                                       K : RawRepresentable,
                                       K.RawValue : Hashable {

    /// A helper method
    func decode<T>(into object: inout [K.RawValue : Any], _ type: T.Type,
                 forKey key: Key) throws where T : Decodable {
        object[key.rawValue] = try self.decode(type, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh the `K.` access!! the `T.Type` and my use of `K.RawValue` should've been a hint, I guess I figured `RawValue` would've been "expanded" just like the generic `K` was in the constraint. Thank you for the response, that did it.

Comment: Yes , it wouldn’t let me accept an answer that soon after posting the question.